# Have more than one mysql version installed at a time

Tags: 14.04, mysql

I currently have mysql 5.5 installed, and working.

I'd like to migrate everything to mysql 5.7 (for a number of reasons, but mostly the spatial functions).

I would like to have both 5.5 and 5.7 be running at the same time on the same box.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 1):

There are problems here in attempting to do what you are asking and keeping your package manager happy.

Off the top, I see two choices here:

1. compile/install from scratch to an entirely different directory hierarchy
2. If I recall, there is a way to install packages using a different base root directory.  Do that and then manually make the necessary changes.

Either way, there could be some effort involved.

Comment: How do I do #2?

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to have both MySQL servers running on the same machine but, it'll take some work.

First you would need to install 5.7 in a different directory than 5.5. Also since MySQL uses a default port, you would need to run 5.7 on a different port.

You're basically creating an entire new MySQL server

[update-alternatives](http://linux.die.net/man/8/update-alternatives) is a program that could work for you as well. (I have not tested this)

```
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/mysql-server mysql-server /usr/bin/mysql-5-1/bin/mysql-server 10
update-alternatives --install /usr/bin/mysql-server mysql-server /usr/bin/mysql-5-6/bin/mysql-server 10
```

--install adds a new mapping

/usr/bin/mysql-server is the link location (where mysql-server normally is located)

mysql-server is the name of the mapping
/usr/bin/mysql-5-6/bin/mysql-servera is where I placed the new version of mysql-server

10 is the priority

You then choose which version of mysql-server you want like so

```
update-alternatives --set mysql-server /usr/bin/mysql-5-6/bin/mysql-server
```

Comment: How can I install it to a different folder?

Comment: I think the easiest way to accomplish this would be to use, [http://mysqlsandbox.net/index.html], kind of a virtualization, if you just want to test out 5.7, then upgrade later.

Comment: Edit the comment to fix

Comment: http://mysqlsandbox.net/index.html I also updated my answer with another option